# "Fall in love with" (non-romantic)

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras

**English:**

In English, you can use the phrase "to fall in love with" with people who you aren't literally in love with. For example, when talking about children, you might say:

> You just fall in love with those cute kids as soon as you see them.

Is *enamorarse* appropriate in that context, or does it always have romantic implications? If not, what is the best translation?

Also, how would you translate "cute" as used in that sentence?

---

**Español:**
En inglés, se puede usar la frase "to fall in love with" con gente con la que no estas literalmente enamorado. Por ejemplo, cuando hablas de niños, se puede decir:

> You just fall in love with those cute kids as soon as you see them.

¿Es *enamorarse* apropiado en ese contexto, o siempre tiene implicaciones románticas? Sino, ¿cuál es la mejor traducción?

Además, ¿como se traduce "cute" tal como se usa en esa frase?

Comment: "Cute" can be hard to translate here because English happens to have a rich and subtle vocabulary of diminutive adjectives like cute, precious, tiny, silly, pretty, little, and so on.  Spanish often uses common diminutive suffixes (-ito, -cito) and a few words (see Kiko_L's answer) to accomplish the same thing but those won't be exact one-to-one matches.

Comment: @Brian: I strongly disagree; Spanish also has a rich and subtle vocabulary in this semantic field. In fact, I can find a number of ways to translate "cute" into Spanish without recurring to diminutive suffixes. "Mono" is probably be the most usual translation in the region of Spain where I live.

Comment: There is a thread on this site specifically addressing the "cute" portion of your questions here:  http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/1840/how-might-you-say-a-child-is-cute-in-spanish/1879#1879

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would translate:

> You just fall in love with those cute kids as soon as you see them.

As:

> Simplemente te van a encantar esos adorables niños en cuanto los veas.

Here I would translate `cute` as as `adorable`.

Answer (score 5):

Actually you can use "*Enamorar*" in than case, for example:

> Te enamoras de esos preciosos niños nada más verles

"*cute*" can be translate into "precioso", "bonito", "bello", "hermoso" or in a more colloquial way (in Spain) "mono", for example:

> Those boys are really cute [*Esos chicos/niños son realmente/muy
>   monos*]

Answer (score 3):

Yes,

> Te enamoras de esos bellos niños apenas los ves

seems right, although probably not what a native speaker would say.

This:

> Los niños son bellos y encantadores

sounds better

Comment: Actually I am a native speaker and I use it like that all the time, as most people I know.

Answer (score 3):

Actually you can say:

> Me encariñé de esos niños tan tiernos (bonitos) tan pronto los vi

Or:

> Me encantaron esos niños tan lindos desde que los vi

I hope this helps

Comment: But tierno != bonito and encariñar != enamorar

Comment: good point but for a native speaker sounds right you can not translate literally the whole sentence

Comment: You're right. Mine was just a warning for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

> Te **enamoraras** de esos niños apenas los veas

But certainly is not what a man would say to another man. It's more like man-to-woman, woman-to-woman, woman-to-man expression

You always can use:

> Te **encariñaras** de esos niños a penas los veas
>
> Te **agradaran** esos niños a penas los veas

Comment: "apenas" [Es hoy infrecuente y desaconsejable su escritura en dos palabras: Marca de incorrección](http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltGUIBusDPD?clave=apenas&origen=RAE)